# Build worker queue with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, queue, worker

I'm, trying to make a worker using this repo and redis

https://github.com/yidas/codeigniter-queue-worker

but i don't find any complete tutorial how to use it. I've tried to use it manual but no luck and keep throwing error, i don't know how to completely build the worker.

if there's any of you have tried or using it, please help to build worker with this lib.

I need to grab around 1 million or more data and build a new database from that data, and i think can't be done by just using 1 single call query, that's why i'm trying to grab all data by using worker so those data can be grabbed consistently without any error.

TRY CASE
I'm trying to load the lib with "use"

```
<?php if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit ('No direct script access allowed!');

use vendor\yidas\queue\sec\Controller' as WorkerController;

class User_register_unverified extends WorkerController{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index(){
        echo 'Test';
    }

}
```

I Got this Error

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: ParseError

Message: syntax error, unexpected '' as WorkerController;' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Filename: /var/www/html/lists/services/application/controllers/User_register_unverified.php

Line Number: 9

Backtrace:

File: /var/www/html/lists/services/index.php
Line: 320
Function: require_once
```

I Try to move the lib to "libraries" codeigniter directory and use require_once and i change the class name to "Worker"

```
<?php if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit ('No direct script access allowed!');

// use vendor\yidas\queue\sec\Controller' as WorkerController;
require_once APPATH.'libraries/Worker' as WorkerController;

class User_register_unverified extends WorkerController{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index(){
        echo 'Test';
    }

}
```

Also get same error

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: ParseError

Message: syntax error, unexpected 'as' (T_AS)

Filename: /var/www/html/lists/services/application/controllers/User_register_unverified.php

Line Number: 4

Backtrace:

File: /var/www/html/lists/services/index.php
Line: 320
Function: require_once
```

Then i tried to use as lib

```
<?php if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit ('No direct script access allowed!');

// use vendor\yidas\queue\sec\Controller' as WorkerController;
// require_once APPATH.'libraries/Worker' as WorkerController;

class User_register_unverified extends CI_Controller{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->worker  = $this->load->library('worker');
    }

    function index(){
        echo 'Test';
    }

}
```

and i got this notif

```
An Error Was Encountered
Non-existent class: Worker
```

I noticed that i did wrong type directory in "use" way and repaired it

```
<?php if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit ('No direct script access allowed!');

use vendor\yidas\queue\src\Controller as WorkerController;

class User_register_unverified extends WorkerController{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        // $this->worker  = $this->load->library('worker');
    }

    function index(){
        echo 'Test';
    }

}
```

Yet, still get the same error

```
Fatal error: Class 'vendor\yidas\queue\src\Controller' not found in /var/www/html/lists/services/application/controllers/User_register_unverified.php on line 6
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Error

Message: Class 'vendor\yidas\queue\src\Controller' not found

Filename: controllers/User_register_unverified.php

Line Number: 6

Backtrace:
```

Comment: that link provides very nice and complete documentation! Did you follow it? Where did you run into trouble? what have you tired so far? Right now your question needs more detail/focus

Comment: Hi, im following every step the documentation's showing.
I try to use the Worker class and extends to my controller right from vendor directory (if installed by composer) and also try to move the Controller class to my libraries directory, i tried to call it with "Use" and also "Required Once",,,,"use" function show error "as" alias, and require_once show notif "Can not find Controller Class" which is the name of that worker class.

Comment: Are you using CI 3.x, right?

Comment: Yes, i updated my post, please take a look

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
    <?php
use yidas\queue\worker\Controller as WorkerController;

class Job extends WorkerController {
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, 
such as citations or documentation.You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center. 
See [How to Answer]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Use `require 'vendor/autoload.php';`.

```
<?php
//use yidas\queue\worker\Controller as WorkerController;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

class Job extends WorkerController {
```